# Jenkins build crash on android Emulator (functional tests)

Tags: android, jenkins, android-emulator, functional-testing

I have the following message on each build (headless server):

> Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed
>   due to 'Process crashed.''. Check device logcat for details Tests on
>   hudson_en-US_240_WVGA_android-18_armeabi-v7a(AVD) - 4.3 failed:
>   Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'

This is the emulator command:

> emulator64-arm -no-boot-anim -ports 5629,5630 -prop persist.sys.language=en -prop persist.sys.country=US -avd hudson_en-US_240_WVGA_android-18_armeabi-v7a -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -no-audio

I`m using Jenkins with Android emulator and xvnc plugins. When the build is being running the functional tests, it`s always crashes. I don`t know why, and it is very confusing. Already tried a lot of things, like: 
- with or without -no-window

Comment: Did tests work on real devices/local emulator

Comment: on real device in local environment they are working. I mean, some of them are failing, but the build process getting completed.
On server we have no chance to use real device, only emulator. please mind that, the server is headless.

Comment: Did jenkins user (on server) have permision to run emulators?

Comment: What did the logcat say?

Comment: I can`t reach the logcat, I have permissions, because if I skip the functional tests it build is becoming green.

Comment: @karoly Did you solved the problem I'm facing something similar right now, I have this output from jenkins:

$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5826
[android] Waiting for emulator to finish booting...
$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5826 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
error: device offline

Comment: Hi, I can check the exact config 4 you at Monday, but the problem was where, that emulator shows a dialog above our application, so the tests was not able to touch the screens :) 
Second: make a large emulator, where all the contents fits on the screen, just for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I can check the exact config 4 you at Monday, but the problem was where, that emulator shows a dialog above our application, so the tests was not able to touch the screens :) Second: make a large emulator, where all the contents fits on the screen, just for sure.